# Read log files on JBoss AS 7

Tags: file, logging, jboss, jboss7.x

I have an application running on JBoss AS 7 and creating log files in `/standalone/log`.

For security reasons I not allowed to browse JBoss directories.
Is there any build-in application to read these logs files from a browser ?

NB : I cannot use admin console either.

Comment: My condolences. A developer is not allowed to view the logs of the server he is working with...this is really sad. Seriously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, nothing built in.  You can have the admins [configure the logging service](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) to put logs where you can get to them, or you can configure the logger to capture logs and post to a database or other.

Comment: Note though, JBoss AS 7 does not use log4j as it's log manager.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet, but there are some requests for it (one by me, BTW ;-) and it might appear in WildFlz 8. Hopefully. (Vote on them if you like.)

- [WFLY-1048](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-1048) Allow hooking into logging subsystem through Management API
- [WFLY-1144](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-1144) Provide the ability to view server logs through the web interface
- [WFLY-280](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-280) Provide an operation to retrieve the last 10 errors from the log

Until then, I suggest to ask the admins to allow access to that one particular log file.

If that doesn't pass through, you may declare dependency of your deployment on a logging service's modules (`Dependencies: ...` in `MANIFEST.MF`) and the log manager in JVM. Unless there's some additional obstacle like security manager or so.