# JBoss 6.3.0.GA How to access logs via web browser

Tags: logging, jboss, jboss-eap-6

### Situation

We are using JBoss 6.3.0.GA on Windows Server 2012 R2 with jdk1.7.0_80 and are currently still in a setup phase, therefore we still have full access to that server.

However, after all installations on that server are finished, we won't have direct access (e.g. via Remote Desktop Connection) anymore.
Since we have to support the applications deployed on that JBoss, we have the need to look into the logs under `$jboss\standalone\log`.

As mentioned, we now still have the chance to configure specific ports/adjust configuration on the JBoss. The idea was to provide somehow read access to all (or at least named) logs beneath that folder, so that we can look into them using a web browser (http/ftp/...).
We already found the logging configuration in the JBoss Management Console but no possibility to look into a specific file.

### References

While searching I found a similar topic concerning JBoss AS 7, but with even more restrictions. Therefore I still want to raise this question.
[Read log files on JBoss AS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15952266/read-log-files-on-jboss-as-7)

### Question(s)

**First:** How can we enable us to look into (read access sufficient) log files beneath `$jboss\standalone\log` (all or explicitly configured) via a web browser (http/ftp/...), preferably by using JBoss build in features?
**Alternatively:** Is there a "simple" way to configure these files as (somehow) downloadable?
**If both negative:** Do you see other/simpler solutions than just to put the log files in some folder and setup a dedicated FTP-Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's nothing built in to JBoss EAP 6.3. In JBoss EAP 6.4 there is a Log Viewer available on the web console.

You could however use something like the ELK stack and have centralized logging. Here's a [blog post](http://wildfly.org/news/2015/07/25/Wildfly-And-ELK/) on how to do that with WildFly. This would work with JBoss EAP 6.3 as well if you're running on at least Java SE 7. You would need to install the javax.json.api module and implementation module too. Or just put the required libraries in the `org.jboss.logmanager.ext` module and make them resources.